# MySQL Prepared Statement Syntax

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have been fighting for my life with prepared statements.  Every site I've tried has different syntax.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT IdNum FROM TOAWorkOrdersNew WHERE WorkDate = ? AND TechNum = ?");
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT IdNum FROM CallVolume WHERE WorkDate = ? AND ANI = ?");

---loop
    ----loop

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $IncDate, $TechNum);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$WorkOrders = $stmt->num_rows;
$SubWorkOrders = $SubWorkOrders + $WorkOrders;

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();


$stmt2->bind_param('ss', $IncDate, $CellNum);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->store_result();


$CallCount = $stmt2->num_rows;
$SubCallCount = $SubCallCount + $CallCount;

$stmt2->free_result();
$stmt2->close();

    }
}
```

The statements are returning NULL.

Comment: Which statements are returning NULL?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `$stmt->close()` inside the loop. Once you close the statement, it no longer remembers what it was prepared with.

Also, you don't need to call `$stmt->bind_param()` each time through the loop. Parameters are bound to references, so you can do this once before the loop, and then just update the variables inside the loop.